# Get Chrome tab asynchronously with AngularJS

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, angularjs

In an AngularJS app (a Chrome extension) I need to get the title and URL of the current tab, before I can do anything useful. This function takes a callback, which receives the tab in question. But instead of logging the tab object, I want to pass it to a module / service as soon as it's available. How can I do this?

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
    console.log(tabs[0]);
});
```

*chrome.tabs.query()* apparently has no return value.

**Edit**
I'm stuck. I tried to get your example to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/yW5G7/

After failing, I put in a very simple test-service to show that the rest of the app works. Maybe someone can fix my service in the commented-out block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use a lazy initialization of AngularJs or create a service that returns a promise to asynchronously resolve the tab info.

Lazy initialization:

- Remove the ng-app directive and [manually bootstrap Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap) when you have the info:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
  angular.bootstrap(document);
});
```

Async service with [promise](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q):

```js
module.service('Chrome', function($q) {
  return function() {
    this.getInfo = function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs) {
        deferred.resolve(tabs[0]);
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    };
  };
});
```

The best approach depends on how much your initialization process depends on the tab vs how much getting this info is important to address an specific part of your extension.